# Which one to use, AngularUI Bootstrap or AngularStrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am a novice to AngularJS and its amazing. I need Twitter's bootstrap plugins in my projects. I stumbled upon these two GitHub projects

1. AngularStrap http://mgcrea.github.com/angular-strap/
2. And AngularUI's bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/

Now, I am confused which one to choose. Are these production ready? or should I use the jQuery extensions which comes with Bootstrap.

Comment: Adding cross-link to another [AngularUI Bootstrap vs AngularStrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097971/angular-ui-vs-angular-strap) question to update "linked"/"related" sections.

Comment: how is this not constructive? I find it a bit odd, that the creator of one of the two libraries under comparison, would vote to stop the comparison ;)

Answer (score 24):

Both projects aim at including Twitter's bootstrap widgets as AngularJS directives, so you can use them in a clean way.
Since none of them cover the complete list of Bootstrap elements, you can use which ever you need, depending on the Bootstrap element you wish to include in your project.
I'm currently including both and so far there are no issues at all.

Comment: These two projects have strongly diverging and mutually-exclusive philosophies, so it is *not* a good idea to use them side-by-side. It is only a matter of time until there is a fatal collision.

Comment: Could you clarify by what you mean they are differning in philosophy. Im new to javascript. The functionality looked more or less same.

Comment: Angular Strap reuses JQuery and Bootstrap's JS so it requires that code, soe there is extra code to 'translate' between the layers. AngularUI rewrites the bootstrap components using only Angular. So angular Strap is 'feature complete' since it is just wrapping bootstrap, but AngularUI is not totally feature complete since it is still rewriting components. AngularUI uses less dependencies.

Comment: The latest version of AngularStrap (v2) does not require JQuery o Bootstrap's JS.

Comment: To add to the last comment, the latest version of AngularStrap also collides with AngularUI Bootstrap (on $tooltip), and cannot be included side-by-side.

Comment: See this discussion re status of these two projects: https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-bootstrap/issues/25

Comment: So what does using one of these options solve? What about using native Bootstrap with AngularJS?