# Angular-UI vs Angular-Strap

Tags: angularjs

So currently I'm using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but I've noticed [Angular-Strap](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap) has been re-written to not be jQuery wrapped directives.

Going through the new code of Angular-Strap I've noticed some pretty nice improvements such as touch and more enhanced functionality over Angular UI.  Angular Experts, what is your current perspective on the two at the moment?

Comment: I Suggest you to use Angular-Strap

Comment: @JQueryGuru - Any feedback to why you suggest this?

Comment: The new one does not ...

Comment: This bothers me too. My gut feeling says that Angular Strap is the better choice at the moment because it is more feature complete. But i  have very little experience with both.

Comment: I ended up migrating my code to AngularStrap.  The project seems to be more active ( recently ) with a more consistent code base.  Along with some of the extra features that I liked there was quite a bit of code reduction that happened from the refactor.

Comment: @amcdnl That is not correct what you say. According to the angular-strap website: "With no external dependency except the Bootstrap CSS styles, AngularStrap is lighter and faster than ever as it does leverage the power of ngAnimate from AngularJS 1.2+!"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I know that the Angular-UI team has worked hard to remove all jQuery and Bootstrap dependencies from their code, the same as Angular Strap. They both support Bootstrap 3x so you gain nothing by going with a specific library from that perspective either. It really comes down to what features are implemented between the two.

If there are features you need that Angular Strap has that Angular-UI doesn't go with Angular Strap. The same can be said for Angular-UI. It really gets down to which one best fits your development.

Comment: Agreed.  They both have things the other doesn't have, wish we could just merge the two! :)

Comment: Just as an example: The datepicker from angular-ui looks much better and has more features than the angular-strap datepicker e.g. number of weeks are shown vertically.

Comment: Another difference is that you can inject html templates in popover with angular-strap

Comment: @CodingSmackdown: Uninstall it immediately because bower brought in jquery as a dependency.

Comment: I use Angular-Strap.  Seems to work well, but the documentation is mediocre.

Comment: if using the breeze with the zValidate directive Angular strap works out of the box for the datepicker - was the deciding factor for me

Comment: i just don't understand why examples of angular-strap are not working on plunker. It is unbelieveable embarrassing with a poor documantation.