# Angular UI Bootstrap vs. AngularStrap vs Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-strap

I have been researching options to using Bootstrap with Angular and it appears to focus on two:

```
Angular UI Bootstrap
AngularStrap
```

I see a third option of just using native Bootstrap. What are the pro/cons of all approaches? This seems to hint that Angular UI Bootstrap is not feature complete:

[Which one to use, AngularUI Bootstrap or AngularStrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240244/which-one-to-use-angularui-bootstrap-or-angularstrap)

Comment: I would definitely advise against trying to use Bootstrap's jQuery plugins with Angular. Use one of the Angular-specific options. jQuery and "the Angular way" have some incompatibilities. Bootstrap's JS isn't super-awesome anyways.

Comment: The main issue I am having is with the navigation. Specifically the navbar dropdown once it hits a mobile breakpoint. I am concerned that I will have to write a lot of code to make up for what comes with Bootstrap, but if there are issues with compatibility between jQuery I will need to watch for those.

Comment: pretty much just base on your need or what you actually going to need. If me I pick AngularStrap since it depend on angular only, I always try to avoid jquery all the time and migrate to angular. jquery can solve short term issue, but if you heavily using it within angular, you might run into pile up issue later on. I rather not spend a day or a week just to debug jquery + angular. As if you  actually try to cross a lake with a single log raft, every time the log roll you roll into the water.

Comment: Is there a list of where jquery and angular collide? I too am avoiding jquery, but if it comes up I want to be aware of what to look for.

Comment: angular-ui bootstrap no longer depends on jquery " As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required."  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use both of them because I don't want my project depends on too many 3rd party libraries. So I just use native Bootstrap JS, but I have to customize it to fit requirement of my project.

I don't say Angular UI Bootstrap and AngularStrap are not good, but with my project's requirement, I don't need all features so they are quite heavy. I just want you to pay attention to a point: currently, AngularStrap supports AngularJS 1.2+, this means it should support IE8 but Angular UI Bootstrap doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Hi in my case its not about either or, its about getting things done. If a component or directive exists already from aforementioned libraries (probably isn't much difference between angular ui bootstrap and angularstrap) e.g. modal, datepicker and it fits requirements then I'll use it. Otherwise I use vanilla  bootstrap to make my own directives :-)

[Here's a link to building components using directives in angular.](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives)